# Introduced Value with Category

Tags: javascript, jquery

In what I'm making, you introduce values into a Input Text, that has an ID of `Inpt1` and goes all the way to 5.

If jQuery finds a correlation to those values in an array, it will place the correspondant value of the array `app_end` in the `label` in front of it with the ID `Inpt1_L`, in other words, the associated category.

Here is how the code looks below:

```
 var choices = ['Cookie', 'Meat', 'Milk']; // The Choices available
 var app_end = ['(CookieCategory)', '(MeatCategory)', '(MilkCategory)']; // Their appendages


    var elem2 = $('#Inpt1_L');
    $('#Inpt1').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    // Save current value of element
    elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());

    // Look for changes in the value
    elem.bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", 
    function(event){

     if (elem.data('oldVal') != elem.val()) {

         var lowercasedElem = elem.val().toLowerCase();
         // Run through array
         for (i=0;i<choices.length;i++){
                   var appendage_For = app_end[i];

                   if((choices[i].toLowerCase() == lowercasedElem)){

                    elem2.empty();
                    elem2.append(appendage_For);
                    return true;
                 } else {
                    elem2.empty();
                }
             }
        }
    });
});
```

I'm trying to make it so that the comparison can also pick up any kind of text before and after. As in, someone can type milk, but they can also type Goat Milk or Cow Milk Light and it will still categorize it as Milk.

So far my attemps have been futile. I've tried creating:

```
if(
   (choices[i].toLowerCase() == lowercasedElem) || 
   (choices[i].toLowerCase() == lowercasedElem+"") || 
   (choices[i].toLowerCase() == ""+lowercasedElem+"")
  ){
```

But nothing happened. Not even with spaces.

`.substr` came to mind but I'm not sure how to apply it to this situation.

How could I achieve the intended?

And secondly, encapsulating all of this code, into a function, and applying a `For(){}` to count through the number of fields with the class #Inpt, would it make this function re-useable?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: this is not the case for you to use [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) ?

Comment: @ElmerDantas Possibly. I applied `if(lowercasedElem.indexOf((choices[i].toLowerCase())) > -1){` and it's still detecting as before... but still have the same problem, I'm afraid

Comment: are you debugging your code? you only need to check `indexOf` the others `==` operations you can remove. This should do what you want...**Goat Milk or Cow Milk Light** will return true for choice `Milk` if is not, your're missing something.

Comment: I have been debugging my code. I was only listing the options I tried beforehand.
I've done ` if(lowercasedElem.search((choices[i].toLowerCase())) > -1)` and that seems to be working as intended. Going to edit. Although now, when I get back to said field and delete it, the category remains there until I start typing in again. Probably an issue with detection.

Comment: your question was about "the comparison can also pick up any kind of text before and after" so...this is done. I can post the `indexOf` solution as answer and you accept it or you can just close/delete this question and create a new one with the new problem you're facing. Avoid asking multiple questions as part of one question.

Comment: Understood. Please do. Although what worked was `.search`. IndexOf wasn't exactly working. Thank you.

Comment: Even better that you find out the `search` method as well...glad to have helped. regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [Elmer Dantas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4335507/elmer-dantas), I was able to narrow down what I needed.

I changed the if condition to use `.search` and it worked.

Here is the code below and the functioning snippet.

```
if(lowercasedElem.search((choices[i].toLowerCase())) > -1)
```

```js
var choices = ['Cookie', 'Meat', 'Milk'];
var app_end = ['(CookieCategory)', '(MeatCategory)', '(MilkCategory)'];

var elem2 = $('#Label1_L');
$('#Inpt1').each(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
  elem.bind("propertychange change keypress click keyup input paste select reset", function(event) {
    elem2.empty();
    if (elem.data('oldVal') != elem.val()) {
      var lowercasedElem = elem.val().toLowerCase();
      for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        var appendage_For = app_end[i];
        if (lowercasedElem.search((choices[i].toLowerCase())) > -1) {
          elem2.empty();
          elem2.append(appendage_For);
          return true;
        } else {
          elem2.empty();
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="Inpt1">
      <label id="Label1_L"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```